# WPF Popup Control - Find X, Y Coordinates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup

I'm trying to get the X,Y coordinates of a popup control.  I have tried:

VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(Popup);

but the vector returned always contains (0,0) for X and Y.

The parent of the popup is the layout root, which is a grid.

The CustomPopupPlacementCallback also always returns 0,0 for it's Point parameter.

The goal is to allow the user to drag the popup anywhere on the screen.  I was going to try and accomplish this by getting the current popup and mouse position, and moving the popup in the same direction of the mouse moves.

--------------------Update--------------------

Chris Nicol, I have tried your answer with the following code, but still receive 0,0 for rootPoint:

Xaml:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="800" Height="600">    

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Popup x:Name="Popup" IsOpen="True" Placement="Center" Width="100" Height="100">
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Test" />
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GeneralTransform transform = Popup.TransformToAncestor(LayoutRoot);
        Point rootPoint = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not find a solution. Sorry for long delay.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the best way of finding that out, but it does work:

```
GeneralTransform transform = controlToFind.TransformToAncestor(TopLevelControl);
            Point rootPoint = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Comment: Yes, that *is* the best way to do it.  I usually do it in a single line:  `controlToFind.TransformToAncestor(TopLevelControl).Transform(new Point(0,0))`

Comment: yup, likewise, I do it in one line.  I just separated it for the example so that it's easier to understand

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, check my update if you have time.

Comment: I've tried to use TransformToAncestor method in ContextMenu.OnMenuOpened event handler and I have got an exception "The specified Visual is not an ancestor of this Visual."

Answer (score 1):

You must use win32 api:

add this to your class:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int Left; // X coordinate of topleft point
        public int Top; // Y coordinate of topleft point
        public int Right; // X coordinate of bottomright point
        public int Bottom; // Y coordinate of bottomright point
    }
```

for finding X,Y coordinates input this to your code (in rect you have requested coordinates):

```
        IntPtr handle = (PresentationSource.FromVisual(popup.Child) as HwndSource).Handle;

        RECT rect = new RECT();
        GetWindowRect(handle, out rect);
```

Comment: This solution only for windows forms and typical windows, not for WPF/Xaml